# Can I fit a bell curve to binomial data points?

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I performed an experiment where participants jumped over a hurdle. Lift off distances and collisions/successes for two cohorts were recorded.

I was doing logistic regressions (`success ~ lift_off_distance`), when I noticed that success rates decreased closer to the hurdle:

[image: dramatic reenactment]

(dramatic reenactment, original datapoints are 0 (collision) or 1 (success), a histogram with binned success rates would look like the drawing above)

A logistic regression would predict a 100% success rate even for liftoff points behind the hurdle which is clearly wrong.

---

Alternatively I have now used a (not normalized) standard distribution fitted to the 0/1 datapoints, with the idea that this gives me the "most successful" position as the mean and variability as the variance of the distribution. This of course is a non-linear regression, fitted with least squares.

---

TL;DR and to make this a question: Can I use a normal distribution instead of the logistic one as my data looks more like a bell curve?

Bonus: I probably have not invented this, how is this called? Just plain non-linear regression?

Comment: Could it be that you want to measure the *amount* of successes against distance from hurdle? If the amount is a discrete number, then a negative binomial regression would work well.

Comment: @HuyPham not exactly. I am more interested in the distribution of the parameter than the result. Ie: "does the lift off distance of successful traversals differ between the groups". Either way, the negative binomial regression would probably fit the data well I think. But, without having too much of a statistical background, I it should be a function that scales up to 1 (like the logit function does)?